# Jquery touch events apply is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where I make drag and drop. To be possible to make drag and drop and also scroll the page without drag and drop I apply the Jquery Touch.

The problem is when I make a tab in table it shows an error in console.

This is the **error**

```
jquery.js:4737 Uncaught TypeError: ((jQuery.event.special[handleObj.origType] || {}).handle || handleObj.handler).apply is not a function
at HTMLTableElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4737)
at triggerCustomEvent (jquery.mobile-events.js:846)
at HTMLTableElement.tapFunc2 (jquery.mobile-events.js:498)
at HTMLTableElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4737)
at HTMLTableElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4549)
```

The code is this:

```
$('.touchtable').tap('tap', function(e) { 
   console.log('hola2');
});
```

How can I fix the error?

The info I read about jquery-touch is here

https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Touch-Events

**Code to drag and drop**

```
if ($('.touchtable').on('doubletap',function(e){

$("#tbodyproject").sortable({

    items: "> tr",
    appendTo: "parent",
    helper: "clone",
    placeholder: "placeholder-style",
    containment: ".table",
    start: function(event, ui) {

        var cantidad_real = $('.table thead tr th:visible').length;
        var cantidad_actual = $(this).find('.placeholder-style td').length;

          if(cantidad_actual > cantidad_real){
          var cantidad_a_ocultar = (cantidad_actual - cantidad_real);

          for(var i = 0; i <= cantidad_a_ocultar; i++){
              $(this).find('.placeholder-style td:nth-child('+ i +')').addClass('hidden-td');
          }
        }

        ui.helper.css('display', 'table')
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.css('display', '')
    },
    update: function( event, ui ) { 
        let newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'/admin/projects/updateOrder',
            data: {ids: newOrder}
        })
       .done(function( msg ) {
        location.reload();        
       });
    }
}).disableSelection();

}));
```

Comment: why if?????????

Comment: I want to be available to make scroll(page) and drag and drop. It's not a good idea to make an if and when user make double tap make scroll. If not enter to if, user can scroll.

Comment: your if condition doesn't make sense. i don't think this will work

Comment: And how I should to it? @BhojendraNepal

Answer (score 1):

Code must be like this:

```
$('.touchtable').on('doubletap', function(e) { 
    console.log('User tapped touchtable'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `on` method instead `tap` method and pass the `tap` parameter on the `on` method which would call you the `tap` method.

```
$('.touchtable').on('tap', function(e) { 
   console.log('hola2');
});
```

In another way, you can directly call the `tap` method like this:

```
$('.touchtable').tap(function(e) {
   console.log('hola2');
});
```

Note: The first method is an event delegation method and the second method is direct method. If you have dynamically inserted elements, then you must use event delegation method to make it work.

Comment: Perfect ;) Thanks

Comment: Bad news, works in computer but not in mobile @BhojendraNepal

Comment: Yes, in console (only in mobile device) show this: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.ui.mouse')` in computer don't show anything. Also I put this to try it in mobile: `$('.touchtable').on('doubletap', function(e) { 
            console.log('User tapped touchtable'); 
        }); ` and in console appear the message. What it's wrong in mobile? Doesn't work the drag and drop (same code in computer works, so I don't think code is wrong). I will post the code to make the drag and drop when user make double tap. You see anything wrong?